# How do I change my internet option to open links with google chrome?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

I had a virus attack so avast kicked in with a warning etc.
But after the attack I noticed that in the taskbar my google chrome icon had changed to internet explorer icon. After I did some reseach I found out my internet options ware changed as well.

[image]

It says "Always in Internet Explorer on desktop".
I can't change how to open links, the option is greyed out.
I have set google chrome as my default web browser.
I have windows 10 as OS.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

clk windows start button=settings icon=select default apps=go to web browser and change it there. If you are having problems changing it verify that the latest windows updates are installed as older version had problems here.